# log4net appender to mysql in c# application

Tags: c#, mysql, log4net

I am building a small c# web application (written in mvc). 
I need to log basic info to a database.
I've researched and found log4net to be quite extensive and popular.

I'm using mysql as my underline database.
I found a few samples of how to log using log4net into mysql database, but non seem to work, and they all seem quite outdated.

Does anyone have a code sample for this?

Thank you very much.

Comment: It's a bad sign.  I've heard people rave about log4net, but they are always the ones that already know how it works.  Since it's such a small application, wouldn't you rather use [Trace](http://www.15seconds.com/issue/020910.htm) instead?  It's simple to use and already included in .NET, so you won't need an external library.

Comment: @Robert, I'd normally agree. But I am using this project as a way to learn new stuff \ technologies.

Comment: This is pretty current: http://www.beefycode.com/post/Log4Net-Tutorial-pt-1-Getting-Started.aspx

Comment: @Robert, first I truly appreciate the time you sparing to my question. Since most of the work around log4net is about configurations, I am not sure what else I can do, I am trying my luck with endless combinations. Can't point the finger at anything specific.

Comment: In your question, you need to describe in detail the problem you are having, if you can, and post the relevant code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems to me that you can achieve this logging through the **AdoNetAppender**.  It looks like you can configure the connection type (mysql, oracle, sqlserver etc).

`The connection type (provider) can be specified by setting the connectionType property`
The above was taken from:
http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/sdk/log4net.Appender.AdoNetAppender.html

I'll try to follow up with an example config for this but I think they do a fair job of explaining how to do this with a sql server database and it seems like you would just need to change the **connectionString** and **connectionType** properties.